# AdMob real ads not appearing

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have not published my app. I have tested it with Admob test ad and it works fine. But with real ads, the ads not showing up. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, your ADMOB account will work after verification. It may take a day or two days

Comment: I released my app to amazon app store, still real ads are not showing up. I ran my app in android studio and log shows:-failed to load ad : error code 3. Is there anything i can do?